# In a snake game, how can a move a snake that has distinct pieces?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, canvas, coffeescript

I've looked at some [examples](http://odhyan.com/blog/2010/10/snake-in-javascript/) that build a snake game in javascript and they seem to move the snake with this algorithm:

1. place a piece where you're going to be next tick
2. remove the last piece from your tail.

This gives the effect of the snake moving around.  But this only works if the snake is one solid color.  I'm trying to make a snake game where each part of the snake is going to be visually different like so:

[image: multi colored snake]

Pretend the black color is the head and the blue is the tail.  The above algorithm wouldn't work for this snake because removing the tail would change the order/color of your "parts".  EG: Your tail would no longer be blue, it would become teal.

What algorithm could I use to to move this snake so that its head says black, its tail stays blue, and all the colors in between stay the same order, too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use the previous algorithm but store colors separately to the pixels.

Assuming you have a list `pixel[0..n]`

which contains the x,y coordinates.

You can create another list `color[0..n]`.

Lets say the original algorithm adds a first pixel and then removes the last pixel.

your display function might have looked like this:

```
for i in 0..n:
    draw(pixel[i], "red")
```

Now you simply go:

```
for i in 0..n:
    draw(pixel[i], color[i])
```

assuming you have a `draw` function that takes a `pixel` and a `color`.

Comment: Awesome, that makes a lot of sense.  And assuming that these aren't pixels but rather shapes or animated images, your algorithm would still work, right?

Comment: yes, instead of color[i], you could use a list of objects to draw.
Then you could go object[i].draw(location=pixel[i])

Comment: I *wish* JavaScript had that syntax :)

Comment: Now that I'm actually doing this, I've confused myself again. If I'm using a list of images and they're 20 pixels wide, but I want the snake to move 5 pixels every tick, how can I use this algorithm.  Am I right in that your algorithm assumes that the snake moves at the speed to add a segment each tick or else it won't work?

Comment: Can't help you on this one sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You would use the existing algorithm, but iterate over all cells, filling the cell with the next cell's colour, to give the impression the snake is *moving*.

You probably have some code that looks like this...

```
if (this.body.length > this.length) {
    var oldPosition = this.body.shift();
    World.setCellAt(oldPosition.x, oldPosition.y, 0);
}

this.body.push({
    x: this.x,
    y: this.y
});
```

Your loop would look something like...

```
this.body.forEach(function(piece, index) {
      var nextPiece = this.body[index + 1];

      if (nextPiece) {
           piece.color = nextPiece.color;
      }

});
```

Comment: Ah, what you've said in English is great and makes perfect sense.  I don't really understand your code though.

Comment: @tieTYT If you set up a jsFiddle with what you have, I'll implement it and explain it for you.

Comment: I appreciate the offer, but I think I've gotten enough info to continue.  I want to try it out on my own.  Thanks anyway!